# Suggestions for creating a rope unravelling sound effect

Tags: foley, sound-effects, sound-design, film-sound-design

I'm doing an audio re-skin of the opening bank heist scene from the Dark Knight. I'm looking for some suggests for recreating the rope unravelling sound when the criminal fires the grappling hook at 1.19-1.20.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OYBEquZ_j0

Any suggestions welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

small skinny rope with a lightly weighted object tied (VERY SECURELY) to the end - record two layers - one of big looping swooshes for the initial flight out the window - maybe a 10 foot extension of the rope, then shorten the rope to 2 feet or so and go much much faster in a circle for the uncoiling.

xlr cable could also work.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely what Rene said, the cable would be have a little more information to record, and be more like that "tactical" rope sound. Also, especially if it's coming off of reels, i'd see if you can get your hands on maybe a fishing reel and pitch down?